# Return row from subselect

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I have this MySQL DB scheme:

```
users (id, login)
coins (userid, value, curr)
```

I need to write select which will return result: login and max coin he have and currency of this coin.

I've tryed something like that:

```
SELECT login, 
(
  SELECT value, curr
  FROM coins 
  WHERE coins.userid = users.id
  ORDER BY value DESC
  LIMIT 1
) AS ROW(value, curr)
FROM users
```

Its not working... I'll recieve error, that "Operand should contain 1 column(s)".
I expected it, but I dont know any way, how to make it.

So i guess: Is there any way to return multiple-column-single-line (row) from subquery to parent query?

(Yes, I can use two subqueries, but its not effective.)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What if there are ties (a user with 2 coins with the same value)?

Comment: Thnx for your answer. It helped me. I meant case with no ties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT u.login, g.MaxVal, c.curr
FROM users u JOIN coins c ON u.id = c.userid 
  JOIN (
    SELECT userid, MAX(`Value`) MaxVal
    FROM coins
    GROUP BY userid
  ) g ON c.userid = g.userid AND c.Value = g.MaxVal
```

In a case of ties, the above query will return all coins with the highest value, if you want to only select 1 of the coins, you can add a `GROUP BY` to the outer query:

```
SELECT u.login, g.MaxVal, c.curr
FROM users u JOIN coins c ON u.id = c.userid 
  JOIN (
    SELECT userid, MAX(`Value`) MaxVal
    FROM coins
    GROUP BY userid
  ) g ON c.userid = g.userid AND c.Value = g.MaxVal 
GROUP BY c.userid
```